# Arch Linux: как установить язык системы английский?

Tags: archlinux, locale, kde

При входе, когда я ввожу логин, переключает на русский. Потом только мышью переключаю и ввожу.
Раскладка русская в системе, другими словами.

Вот так сделал в /etc/locale.conf:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Потом *sudo locale-gen*

Ребутаю, и все равно такая лабуда.
Как бороться?
Спс.

Comment: Это системый файл. Попробуйте изменить ``~/.config/locale.conf``, это настройки пользователя.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Locale

Comment: Такого файла у меня нет.

Answer (score 0):

зайди в настройки , клавиатура , установи сочетание клавиш после reboot
должно сработать

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Может это и будет работать в определённом DE или WM, но у меня, например, нет таких кнопок. Напишите подробнее, где это решение применимо.